# Ext and Openlayers problem color layer

Tags: openlayers-2, ext-js

I had symbolized different layers as you can see here:

```
if (vector_layer.name == "Buffer"){             
vector_layer.style = {fillColor: "blue", pointRadius: 7, fillOpacity: 0.3, 
strokeColor:"#F2F2F2"}; 

vector_layer.addFeatures(geojson_format.read(result.getData()));
legend.loadLayer(vector_layer);
```

It works fine, but the problem is when I try to change the color with Ext JS Library 3.4.0. The fact is with this type of layers, they are results from turf operation and ext js don't allow me to change the color. I try to choose a different color one but I doesn't work.

Code:

```
var cp = new Ext.ColorPalette({value:'993300', "renderTo" : cpid});
                    cp.on("select", function(palette, selColor){
                        console.log("selected: "+selColor);
                        colorPicker.hide();
                        var newStyle = new OpenLayers.Style(
                            {"fillColor" : "#"+selColor, 
                            "strokeColor" :"#"+selColor,
                            "fillOpacity" : 0.4,
                            "strokeOpacity" : 1,
                            "strokeWidth" : 1,
                            "strokeLinecap" : "round",
                            "pointRadius" : 6});
                        layer.styleMap.styles["default"] = newStyle;    
                        layer.redraw();
```

Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: It's unlikely that ExtJS is causing this, you should verify your style change code works correctly outside Ext handler (even if just from your browser's JS console)

Answer (score 3):

This should work: assigning new Stylemap and redraw:

```
var cp = new Ext.ColorPalette({value:'993300', "renderTo" : cpid});

    cp.on('select', function (palette, selColor) {


        var newStyle = new OpenLayers.Style({
            "fillColor": "#" + selColor,
                "strokeColor": "#" + selColor,
                "fillOpacity": 0.4,
                "strokeOpacity": 1,
                "strokeWidth": 1,
                "strokeLinecap": "round",
                "pointRadius": 6
        });


        var sty = OpenLayers.Util.applyDefaults(newStyle, OpenLayers.Feature.Vector.style["default"]);

        var sm = new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
            'default': sty,
                'select': {
                strokeColor: "red",
                fillColor: "red"
            }
        });

        vector_layer.styleMap = sm;


        vector_layer.redraw();

        cp.hide();



    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/expedio/6jtf8m5o/

or another example with more dynamical styling:

http://jsfiddle.net/expedio/nL1md65z/

Answer (score 1):

I got it:

```
if(nameAlgorithm == "Center"){
                    var myStyles = new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
                        "default": new OpenLayers.Style({
                            fillColor: "blue", pointRadius: 7, fillOpacity: 0.3, strokeColor:"#F2F2F2"
                        })
                    });
                    var vector_layer   = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("vector_layer",{   
                        styleMap: myStyles      
                    });             
                }
```